# Babylonjs outline through walls

Tags: babylonjs

I'm trying to make a FPS game using babylon.js as a framework. I want the player to be able to see an outline of their allies through walls (so they can know where they are and what they are doing). As a reference, here is an example I found on google from the game Paladins:

[image: image to describe what I want]

The best thing I could find on the babylon.js website (and on google) is how to do the outline:
(https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/highlight_layer)

```
var hl = new BABYLON.HighlightLayer("hl1", scene);
hl.addMesh(sphere, BABYLON.Color3.Green());
```

While an effect like this is pretty much what I want, it isn't visible though walls. Is anything like this possible in babylon.js? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To render something "on top" of something else you can use rendering groups.

The short documentation can be found here - https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/transparency_and_how_meshes_are_rendered#rendering-groups , but the basic concept is - the higher the rendering group, the later it renders.

You can see it here in action - https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#2338DN#3

There was an active conversation about the same subject in the forum, which can be found here - https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/highlight-through-objects/8002/3 , credit goes to sebvan

Comment: the BABYLON.Mesh.addExcludedMesh() was what I was missing, thanks a lot